# How to setup iptables within VM bridge

Tags: virtualbox, iptables, ip-forward

I have the following system (upper diagram) which edge nodes send UPD dataframes to the central node, however, I want to the central node to forward them to the rest of nodes (bottom diagram). I don't know how to configure the iptables to get it.

[image]

ipv4 is enabled and if run this commands:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i enp0s3 --dport 8947-j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.63:8947
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p udp-i enp0s3 -d 192.168.1.63 --dport 8947 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.60
```

getting this result:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -t nat -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 19 packets, 1478 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  201 15678 DNAT       udp  --  enp0s3 any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:8947 to:192.168.1.63:8947

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 205 packets, 15986 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 216 packets, 16842 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 159 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  400 31191 SNAT       all  --  any    enp0s3  anywhere             anywhere             to:192.168.1.60
```

Mention that .63 also sends UDP packets using the port 8947, is there a conflict? i don't receive the packets from .60. What I'm missing?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want your bridge, which defaults to acting like a switch, to act like a hub. I do not know that iptables is the way to proceed here. [Here is one article I found on making a bridge into a hub](https://techglimpse.com/convert-linux-bridge-hub-vm-interospection/).

Comment: I want a Ubuntu VM (the middle box) to act as a router of UDP dataframes, yes layer 2, in this case.